# how to sort specific in structs and search by last name

Tags: c

I want to know how I could sort elements in structs by score and search by last name.
The program also has a problem; when I enter 1 to print the records it asks me for a new entry and when I press 2 it prints the records and ask me for the entry.
So same thing for both cases — I don't know why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct the_struct
{
 char FirstName[20];
 char LastName[32];
 int  Score[20];
};
int main ()
 {
int i,n,z;
struct the_struct *ptr[100];
printf("how many students?\n");
scanf("%d",&n);

for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{

   ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct the_struct));
   printf("Enter First Name \n");
   scanf("%s",ptr[i]->FirstName);
   printf("Enter Last Name \n");
   scanf("%s",ptr[i]->LastName);
   printf("Enter Score? \n");
   scanf("%s",ptr[i]->Score);
   printf("%s %s %s\n",ptr[i]->FirstName,ptr[i]->LastName,ptr[i]->Score);
    }
printf("Enter the command you want to proceed to.\nprint record (press 1)\nadd new records (press 2)\ndelete record (press 3)\nSearch by last name (press 4)\nSort by score(press 5)\nSort by last name( press 6)\nFind Median score(press 7)\nExit program (press 0)\n");
scanf("%d",&z);
if (z==1);
{
    for (i = 0; i<n;++i)
    {
        printf("%s %s %s\n",ptr[i]->FirstName,ptr[i]->LastName,ptr[i]->Score);
    }
}
if (z==2);
{
   ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct the_struct));
   printf("Enter First Name \n");
   scanf("%s",ptr[i]->FirstName);
   printf("Enter Last Name \n");
   scanf("%s",ptr[i]->LastName);
   printf("Enter Score? \n");
   scanf("%s",ptr[i]->Score);
}


}
```

So I tried to write the sort function but it doesn't work when I print it.

```
if (z==5)
{
     if(strcmp(The_final[i].Score,The_final[i+1].Score)>0)
     {
       temp = The_final[i];
       The_final[i] = The_final[i+1];
       The_final[i+1] = temp;
     }
     printf("%s %s %s\n",ptr[i]->FirstName,ptr[i]->LastName,ptr[i]->Score);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",ptr[i]->Score);` but `int  Score[20];`

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort and write your sorting function for `score`

Comment: `if (z==1);if (z==2);` remove `;`

Comment: `if (z==2)` increment `i`(and `n`)(note : `i` may have changed.)

Comment: You should really enable compiler warnings, or look at them carefully if they are already shown. I'm pretty sure that any reasonable compiler will warn about the two problems @BLUEPIXY pointed out.

Comment: i disabled the compiler warning to practice for final examination
@RetoKoradi  so far not doing that great based on the errors that BLUEPIXY pointed to, which btw worked.

Comment: You probably meant `int  Score;` instead of `int  Score[20];` You want to have one score per struct, not 20. No?

Comment: Don't disable compiler warnings unless your coding is good enough that it would compile without warnings even if you enabled them.  How will you learn when you're making mistakes if you don't have the warnings enabled? Remember: the C compiler knows more about C than you do.